# following a log file over http

Tags: http, logging, text, utilities, tail

For security reasons (I'm a developer) I do not have command line access to our Production servers where log files are written.  I *can*, however access those log files over HTTP.  Is there a utility in the manner of "tail -f" that can "follow" a plain text file using only HTTP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this if the HTTP server accepts requests to return parts of a resource. For example, if an HTTP request contains the header:

> Range: bytes=-500

the response will contain the last 500 bytes of the resource. You can fetch that and then parse it into lines, etc. I don't know of any ready-made clients which will do this for you - I'd write a script to do the job.

You can use [Hurl](http://hurl.it/) to experiment with headers (from publicly available resources).

Comment: +1  This is very helpful.  I had a thought of using a HEAD method to hopefully get the size of the resource to see if anything new had been added.  Coupled with a GET on a specific range I might be on to something.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a bash script for the same purpose. You can find it here https://github.com/maksim07/url-tail

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to execute command on remote computer.
The tail command for windows can be found at http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/

If it has to be HTTP, you can write a light weight web service to achieve that easily.
e.g., read text within a specified file from line 0 to line 200.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to execute anything remotely, that would make the security people apoplectic.  I was hoping something already existed before I tried rolling my own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use small java utility to read log file over Http using Apche HTTP Library.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            response.getEntity().getContent()));
    String s = "";
    while ((s = rd.readLine()) != null) {
       //Process the line
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple bash script to fetch URL content each 2 seconds and compare with local file `output.txt` then append the diff to the same file

I wanted to stream AWS amplify logs in my Jenkins pipeline

```sh
while true; do comm -13 --output-delimiter="" <(cat output.txt) <(curl -s "$URL") >> output.txt; sleep 2; done
```

don't forget to create empty file `output.txt` file first

```sh
: > output.txt
```

view the stream :

```sh
tail -f output.txt
```

**UPDATE:**

I found better solution using wget here:

```sh
while true; do wget -ca -o /dev/null -O output.txt "$URL"; sleep 2; done
```

https://superuser.com/a/514078/603774

Comment: Can the wget option be updated to use curl instead?