# Tail a text file on a web server via HTTP

Tags: logging, coldfusion, shared-hosting, tail

Looking for input on how to solve the following problem. My ColdFusion 9 app has a simple logger that writes text to a file. On my dev machine, the file is local so I can use either 'tail -f' or CFB's TailView to watch it. I'd like a tool to watch it when it's deployed on the production server. The catch: production is at a shared CF hosting provider which doesn't allow RDS file access or a directory-watcher gateway. I'm wondering about a page with a meta refresh tag or if I want to get more fancy, something AJAXy to the same effect. Thoughts? Any tools that already exist for this?

I may experiment with this but am hoping there is something out there "more complete" : [following a log file over http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645549/following-a-log-file-over-http)

Comment: Have a look at http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2009/4/12/Using-ColdFusion-to-get-the-end-of-a-file - you only need to add a refresh each minute or so..

Comment: You can try HTML5's Server-Sent Events if you want good streaming solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can you the following PHP script:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
set_time_limit(0);
passthru("tail -F -n +0 log.txt");
?>
```

Comment: I tried this on Mac OS X on /var/log/syslog and nothing appears in the browser window until I stop the php server. Any idea how to flush the output periodically?

Answer (score 0):

The following psuedo-code is inspired by [this Java solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557844/java-io-implementation-of-unix-linux-tail-f) and has not been tested at all:

```
if (NOT structKeyExists(application, "log") {
    application.log = fileOpen('log.txt', 'read')
}

while(NOT FileisEOF(application.log))  {
    writeOutput(fileReadLine(application.log) & "<br/>");
}
```

Put that on a page with a meta refresh and I think you are probably in business.

Comment: Thanks, orangepips. There are the usual issues with log files such as them being large. I don't want to repeatedly send the same 1MB of data just to get the latest 10 lines. I'm now thinking of something purely client-side using AJAX and HTTP's HEAD request to look at the Content-Length. If that has changed from the previous value, do a GET using the HTTP Range field to only get the updated data to append to the DOM. Seems like something that should already exist so I'm Googling around...

Comment: You're not sending the same data repeatedly because the file reference is only created once and persisted into the application scope. So every refresh only shows newly added lines.

Comment: Ah, of course. How do you think the above will handle log roll-over?

Comment: @DaveBurns: it won't, you'll need to write that algorithm. Presumably you'll know what time or file size the log rolls over. So `fileClose()` the current reference and create anew. Also if your CF server restarts you may need to think about maintaining a line pointer in that situation when in comes back up and iterating forward to where you need to be in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

I create the following bash script for my use case ([tail.sh](https://gist.github.com/habibutsu/5420781))

It with using 'lynx' get list of files from which get filesize that needed, and in infinity loop trying to get part of file

Answer (score -1):

I know it's pretty old school, but have you considered logging to a database? If you timestamp the log entries in the table you could use HTTP Caching headers to communicate to the server what new data you should see.

Comment: It crossed my mind. Logging to databases is one of those things people love or hate - somehow it gets religious. I'm one of those who feels like it's too heavyweight. Good topic for discussion though - thanks.