# IIS Logs and Logstash

Tags: iis, sharepoint-2010, logstash

Im looking at options for analysing SharePoint IIS logs and currently moving the log files to another server and processing with AWStats is the option.

I would like to investigate using ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana). Is it possible to collect the logs using logstash without having logstash on the server?

The log files aren't served so I couldn't use something like [curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24861674/can-logstash-read-directly-from-remote-log) but they are in shared folders.

Comment: try `NXlog`, here are some exist feedback for your question  http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/579913-getting-log-files-from-windows-servers-to-ubuntu-elk-server

Answer (score 0):

Typically you put a 'shipper' on the client machines, which sends the logs to a centralized logstash indexer.  I don't have any Windows boxes, so can't recommend the best shipper for you.

On AWS, people will often put the logs on S3.  There's a plugin for logstash that should be able to read them from there.