# Is there a way to perform a "tail -f" from an url?

Tags: linux, bash, tail

I currently use tail -f to monitor a log file: this way I get an autorefreshing console monitoring a web server.

Now, said webserver was moved to another host and I have no shell privileges for that.
Nevertheless I have a .txt network path, which in the end is a log file which is constantly updated.

So, I'd like to do something like tail -f, but on that url.
Would it be possible?In the end "in linux everything is a file" so..

Comment: Try this : http://superuser.com/questions/514066/tail-f-equivalent-for-an-url

Answer (score 7):

You can do auto-refresh with help of `watch` combined with `wget`.
It won't show history, like `tail -f`, rather update screen like `top`.
Example of command, that shows content on file.txt on the screen, and update output every five seconds:

```
watch -n 5 wget -qO-  http://fake.link/file.txt
```

Also, you can output n last lines, instead of the whole file:

```
watch -n 5 "wget -qO-  http://fake.link/file.txt | tail"
```

In case if you still need behaviour like "tail -f" (with keeping history), I think you need to write a script that will download log file each time period, compare it to previous downloaded version, and then print new lines. Should be quite easy.

Comment: -1 This just downloads whole resource each time. Tailing means keeping an eye on the growing resource and retrieving **new** content when it appears.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a simple bash script to fetch URL content each 2 seconds and compare with local file `output.txt` then append the diff to the same file

I wanted to stream AWS amplify logs in my Jenkins pipeline

```sh
while true; do comm -13 --output-delimiter="" <(cat output.txt) <(curl -s "$URL") >> output.txt; sleep 2; done
```

don't forget to create empty file `output.txt` file first

```sh
: > output.txt
```

view the stream :

```sh
tail -f output.txt
```

original comment : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62347827/2073339

**UPDATE:**

I found better solution using wget here:

```sh
while true; do wget -ca -o /dev/null -O output.txt "$URL"; sleep 2; done
```

https://superuser.com/a/514078/603774

Answer (score 1):

I've made this small function and added it to the `.*rc` of my shell. This uses `wget -c`, so it does **not** re-download the whole page:

```
# Poll logs continuously over HTTP
logpoll() {
    FILE=$(mktemp)

    echo "———————— LOGPOLLING TO $FILE ————————"
    tail -f $FILE &
    tail_pid=$!
    bg %1

    stop=0
    trap "stop=1" SIGINT SIGTERM
    while [ $stop -ne 1 ]; do wget -co /dev/null -O $FILE "$1"; sleep 2; done

    echo "——————————— LOGPOLL DONE ————————————"

    kill $tail_pid
    rm $FILE
    trap - SIGINT SIGTERM
}
```

#### Explanation:

- Create a temporary logfile using `mktemp` and save its path to `$FILE`
- Make `tail -f` output the logfile continuously in the background
- Make <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> set `stop` to `1` instead of exiting the function
- Loop until `stop` bit is set, i.e. until the user presses <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
- `wget` given URL in a loop every two seconds:

  - `-c` - "continue getting partially downloaded file", so that `wget` continues instead of truncating the file and downloading again
  - `-o /dev/null` - `wget`'s log messages shall be thrown into the void
  - `-O $FILE` - output the contents to the temp logfile we've created
- Clean up after yourself: kill the `tail -f`, delete the temporary logfile, unset the signal handlers.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Right. Fixed, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solutions periodically download the full file.

To avoid that I've created a package and published in NPM that does a HEAD request ( getting the size of the file ) and requesting only the last bytes.

Check it out and let me know if you need any help.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@imdt-os/url-tail

Comment: Please explain how to use it here in this post.